# My code isn't working and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, scripting, google-sheets, google-docs

Basically this is supposed to find the values in specific columns of the row and add them together to get a total and place that total in the cell specified. It is not working for some reason.

```
function rating(Irange,Q,Y,AG,AO,AW,BE,BM) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var range = sheet.getRange(Irange);
  var row = Irange.getRow();
  var total = Number(values[row][8]) + 
    Number(values[row][9]) + 
    Number(values[row][10]) +
    Number(values[row][11]) +
    Number(values[row][16]) +
    Number(values[row][17]) +
    Number(values[row][18]) +
    Number(values[row][19]) +
    Number(values[row][24]) +
    Number(values[row][25]) +
    Number(values[row][26]) +
    Number(values[row][27]) +
    Number(values[row][32]) +
    Number(values[row][33]) +
    Number(values[row][34]) +
    Number(values[row][35]) +
    Number(values[row][40]) +
    Number(values[row][41]) +
    Number(values[row][42]) +
    Number(values[row][43]) +
    Number(values[row][48]) +
    Number(values[row][49]) +
    Number(values[row][50]) +
    Number(values[row][51]) +
    Number(values[row][56]) +
    Number(values[row][57]) +
    Number(values[row][58]) +
    Number(values[row][59]) +
    Number(values[row][64]) +
    Number(values[row][65]) +
    Number(values[row][66]) +
    Number(values[row][67]);
  return total;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Which *part* of it isn't working? Getting the sheet? Getting the values from it? Getting the row? (That line `var row = Irange.getRow();` looks a bit suspect...)

Comment: Yeah its erroring on Line 4 the var row = Irange.getRow();

Comment: Its in Google Spreadsheet so I'm having to use GoogleScript which I am less versed than I am with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It looks odd that you're doing

```
var range = sheet.getRange(Irange);
```

...and then not using that `range` for anything. Instead, on the next line, you have:

```
var row = Irange.getRow();
```

I haven't done virtually anything with Google Docs Spreadsheets, but perhaps that should be `range.getRow()` (no `I`), since `Range` objects have a [`getRow` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow%28%29). (Naturally I have no idea what your `Irange` argument is, but it looks like you're using it as a string when calling [`getRange(a1Notation)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28String%29)).